# iphone / ipad application conversion

Tags: iphone

I created application......

Runing in   iphone simulator...which working fine...... tableviewcell size..... DatePicker, Pickerview.....all are aligned perfect........ when i configure the  TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY to IPAD... every things is not  aligned  TableviewCell size for pickerview datepicker Outlets are in different size.......... what to do in this case.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

iPad's screen size is 768x1024, and the iPhone's screen size is 320x480. They are different.